# Remove the part of a string that exists in an array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a string pathname and an array of strings containing country extensions.

```
string url = "/pl/test-page/index.html";
string[] countryExtensions = {"/pl/", "/de/", "/tr/"};
```

What I want to achive is removing that part (/pl/ in the example) if exists in the given array.

if exists I simply want to receive the following url without repeating;

```
string newUrl = "/test-page/index.html";
```

Using that new url I want to print out some metacode only once just like below. I tried to use foreach but it then repeats the same metacode.

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en-US" href="https://example.com/test-page/index.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="pl-PL" href="https://example.com/pl/test-page/index.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="https://example.com/de/test-page/index.html" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="tr-TR" href="https://example.com/tr/test-page/index.html" />
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `string newUrl = "/test-page/index.html";` Why is the `/` at the start still there? Wasn't it removed when you removed `/pl/`?

Comment: could you please post your foreach attempt? I really would like to see why it did not work. Do you have your urls in a separate collection?

Comment: @CaiusJard You're right, I needed to do this: `Array.ForEach(countryExtensions, x => { url = url.Replace(x, ""); });` or you could set the `countryExtensions.ToList().ForEach(x => { url = url.Replace(x, ""); });` Thank you for correcting me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives you what you've asked for, but it seems a bit odd if it's what you want:

```
        string url = "/pl/test-page/index.html";
        string[] ext = {"/pl/", "/de/", "/tr/"};

        //remove the /pl/ and replace with /
        url = url.Replace(ext.FirstOrDefault(x => url.StartsWith(x)) ?? "/", "/");

        //build a list of urls /test.., /pl/test.., /de/test.. and /tr/test..
        var urls = new[] { url }.Concat(ext.Select(x => x.TrimEnd('/') + url));
```

You can use the `urls` to build your HTML (I didn't prefix the "https://example.com")